# How to get simple pivot table using django orm?

Tags: django, orm, django-queryset, django-orm

Simple model with 3 data columns.

input:

```
id  ts  val var
1   1   1   10
2   2   2   20
3   2   3   30
4   1   4   40
5   1   5   50
6   2   6   60
```

output:

```
ts  val     var
1   [1,4,5] [10,40,50]
2   [2,3,6] [20,30,60]
AND
ts  val_var
1   [1,10]  [4,40]  [5,50]
2   [2,20]  [3,30]  [6,60]
```

What should be used: annotate() aggregate() group_by()?

Or even simpler pivot table:

```
ts  val
1   [1,4,5]
2   [2,3,6]
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd have thought iterate through an appropriately ordered queryset. Using `yield` to create a generator is efficient if the queryset is enormous, as opposed to creating an enormous list and then processing that.

NB Untested.

```
def foo1():    

    qs = Whatever.objects.all().order_by( 'ts', 'val')
    vals, vars = [],[]
    for obj in qs:

         if vals and obj.ts != ts:
              yield ts, vals, vars
              vals, vars = [], []

         ts = obj.ts
         vals.append( obj.val)
         vars.append( obj.var)

    yield ts, vals, vars # don't forget the last one
```

Usage:

```
for ts, val, var in foo1():
     print ( ts, val, var)
```

For the second one you just use zip on the results:

```
     print ( ts, *[ x for x in zip( val, var) ])
```

Comment: I would like to use django orm to get the table.